# How to convert PNG image to CMYK in iOS?

Tags: ios, colors, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a set of user-generated PNG images that I need to embed into print-ready PDFs. One of the constraints set by the printing company is that all images be in the CMYK colorspace. How do I convert a PNG (or UIImage containing that PNG) to CMYK? By default the colorspace is sRGB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider [CGColorSpace](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1666370-cgcolorspace) class and [CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceCMYK](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1408897-cgcolorspacecreatedevicecmyk) function. 
You can create a `CGContex` using [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/1455939-init) initializer and pass CMYK color space as a parameter to it. Then just draw a `CGImage` from that context and create UIImage from it.

Example:

```
func createCMYK(fromRGB image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    let size = image.size
    let colorSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceCMYK()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
    guard let context = CGContext(data: nil,
                                  width: Int(size.width),
                                  height: Int(size.height),
                                  bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                  bytesPerRow: 4 * Int(size.width),
                                  space: colorSpace,
                                  bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) else { return nil }            
    context.draw(image.cgImage!, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    guard let cgImage = context.makeImage() else { return nil }
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
}
```

Comment: It does not work. It crashes with "<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: set CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS environmental variable to see the details"

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203 "Supported Pixel Formats" table you must use

```
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)
```

to correctly create a context